# python Gtk.Clipboard.get() gtk3 return value differs

Tags: python, clipboard, gtk3

I want to convert Gtk.Clipboard.get() return value to utf-8.

## gtk3

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def main():
    clip = Gtk.Clipboard.get (Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
    text=clip.wait_for_text ()
    print text
    text=text.encode("utf-8")
    print text 

main()
```

It works only when selected text keeps only ascii characters, but if there are are some national characters (french/german, etc) I get error from text.encode(..) function :
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Have You got idea where is the problem and how to make gtk3 version to work?

This works correct when I use gtk2's gtk.clipboard_get() function:

```
import gtk

def main():
    clip = gtk.clipboard_get ('PRIMARY')
    text=clip.wait_for_text ()
    print text
    text=text.encode("utf-8")
    print text 
main()
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here. The clipboard's `wait_for_text()` method, according to the documentation, is already supposed to give you UTF-8 encoded strings. It might be that the GTK 3 version is mistakenly returning a `str` instead of a `unicode` object. To test this, try adding

```
print type(text)
```

to see what kind of object it is.

You can try `utext = text.decode('utf8')` to get a `unicode` object.

Answer (score 0):

`wait_for_text()` does return `str` type, but this is not mistake: utf-8 strings are represented by `str` type.

It also came to my mind that this line will always produce an error:

```
some_Unicode_String_With_Non_Ascii.encode("utf-8").encode("utf-8"),
```

Thus my gtk3 example behaves correctly. As a conclusion: `text.encode("utf-8")` operation should be removed.